# PyCharm SSH Interpreter Error (illegal option --)

Tags: ssh

I was trying to connect to a remote server (using docker) via ssh interpreter.
This is how I tried to connect (the docker is running perfectly fine).
(on Pycharm) Preferences → Python interpreter → Add SSH Interpreter.

The below image is the error message I've got, and I can't figure out where to even start...
Thank you ahead for your help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after changing my target remote from CentOS to Ubuntu. Turned out the problem was in the shell used by default on the remote machine -- `/bin/sh`.
After I've changed the shell to default `/bin/bash`, removed all SSH settings in PyCharm, invalidated caches (File -> Invalidate caches), restarted the IDE and added the remote connection and interpreter from scratch, everything worked.